# create a link to share a google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need a way to provide a link to a private google calendar that allows the recipient to not just view the calendar, but add the calendar to their list of calendars.  I don't want to add each user's email on the calendar settings, but rather have them click to accept a sharing invitation.

such as "click here to add the training calendar to your google calendars"

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot share private calendar. For you to share it, you need to change it as public for others to view it.

From this [document](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing#sharing_calendars), there are two different ways to share calendar and event data with others.

First, you can share an entire calendar, with a specified level of access. For example, you can create a team calendar, and then do things like:

- Grant all members of your team the right to add and modify events in the calendar
- Grant your boss the right to see the events on your calendar
- Grant your customers the right to only see when you are free or busy, but not the details of the events

You can also adjust the access to individual events on the shared calendar.

Second is you can invite others to individual events on your calendar. Inviting someone to an event will put a copy of that event on their calendar. The invitee can then accept or reject the invitation, and to some extent also modify their copy of the event.

By giving access to the other user,you can [share the calendar](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing#sharing_calendars). The sharing settings of a given calendar are represented by the [ACL collection](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl) (access control list) of that calendar.

For your click/button that you want, I think you need to provide some sample code for that. Or check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763734/how-to-build-html-link-to-a-google-calendar-event) for that.