# Link to add all day event to Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, google-calendar-api

So I looked at [Link to add to google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar), but I want to do the same with an all day event.

I've tried doing `dates={date.getUTCDate()}`, but the link doesn't take me to a google cal add event page (it just takes me to my calendar), I suspect because the date is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763734/how-to-build-html-link-to-a-google-calendar-event)?

Comment: Here you can find a comprehensive guide for google calendar properties: https://github.com/InteractionDesignFoundation/add-event-to-calendar-docs/blob/master/services/google.md

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't put a time in the link it seems to mark the event as all day, for example: 20160627/20160627

So if you want a one day all day event for June 27 it would look like (using the example from "[Link to add to google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar)"):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?
action=TEMPLATE
&text=[event-title]
&dates=20160627/20160627
&details=[description]
&location=[location]
&trp=false
&sprop=
&sprop=name:"
target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Add to my calendar</a>
```

For a 2 day event it would look like **(notice you have to add one extra day)**:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?
action=TEMPLATE
&text=[event-title]
&dates=20160627/20160629
&details=[description]
&location=[location]
&trp=false
&sprop=
&sprop=name:"
target="_blank" rel="nofollow">Add to my calendar</a>
```

Comment: "Notice you have to add one extra day" – this stumped me for a while. Thanks!

Comment: I've bolded that to make it a little more apparent.  I'm not sure why it works like that.

Comment: I just leveraged this post to set custom links to all day. Thanks for the breakdown!