# How to send google calendar event invitations via SMS in android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar, deeplink

is there a way to send google calendar event invitation link(Dynamic link or deep link) via sms,

if yes, how can we do it programmatically.

ex:- i have created by brothers birthday event in my phones calendar, now i wana share it with my family members via sms, create a event link in sms which adds event to their google calendar.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ad-hoc implementation of sending/sharing event invites through SMS even from the 
[Sharing and Attendees](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing). Maybe if you can find a way to 
send [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763734/how-to-build-html-link-to-a-google-calendar-event) through SMS:

```
//CALENDAR_ID is your email
//day&dates format is YYYYMMDD
  https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=yourpersonalemail@gmail.com&mode=day&dates=20170203/20170203
```

then the receiver can copy the link, paste it to his browser and add the event to his calendar. As of now, this the SMS support that Calendar API provides is [SMS reminders](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events):

> "sms" - Reminders are sent via SMS. These are only available for
>   Google Apps for Work, Education, and Government customers. Requests to
>   set SMS reminders for other account types are ignored.

Comment: Thanks @noogui... i will try using the link you have provided and let you know... thanks again :)